# Graphic overlay over form and all controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, graphics

I have a form with lots of nested splitcontainers and listviews and a picturebox and stuff. When certain things happen in my program I want an overlay to appear over everything in a little box in the middle of my form with a short message. Then if possible have it fade away. I thought about just using a panel or something but I'm not sure how best to make it appear over the entire form regardless of other controls. I can only get it to sit inside one splitcontainer at a time rather than floating over all of them. It would also be really handy if it did not interfere with the focus or clicking on my form but that is less important if it is a whole lot more complicated.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: what's wrong with messageBox?

Comment: I don't want these messages to interrupt the use of the program. Kind of like a statusbar but something that can't be overlooked easily.